# 2 dimension array to a function does not pass correctly in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

i have been trying to pass a two dimension character array to a function in c++ and the parameter received in the functions is just random strings

```
void SomeFunction(char arr[][50])
{
   //arr is just random strings
}

int main()
{
  char arr[50][50] = { {"Hello"}, {"World"} };
  SomeFunction(arr);
}
```

Comment: You didn't initialize it, so what did you expect when you read it out? Reading uninitialized values is undefined behavior.

Comment: Work as expected [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9498fd39fd0cb8ff).

Comment: @everyone sorry but i actually have it initialized in my code and i forgot to initialize it here

Comment: Please add implementation of SomeFunction as well, how you are trying to access the information.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, you need to initialize the array values before you read it.

```
void SomeFunction(char arr[][3])
{
   std::cout << arr[0][0];
}

int main()
{
  char arr[3][3] = {
      {'a', 'b', 'c'},
      {'d','e', 'f'},
      {'g', 'h', 'i'},
  };
  SomeFunction(arr);
}
```

In this example I initialize all the array values in a single statement, if you don't initialize or assign values to a specified element and try to access it, a undefined behavior will happen, getting random strings can be garbage located in the memory location that you tried to access.

Comment: Can you provide the initialization code and the code that you use to access the elements in your question? As a minimal way to reproduce it https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example it probably still may fall under some kind of undefined behavior as you're getting random strings

Comment: sorry but i actually have it initialized in my code and i forgot to initialize it here

Comment: There's no problem, just edit your question with a minimal reproducible example so we can know better what is happening, because the code you provided, if initialized and properly accessed is defined behavior, so there must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to initialize the array and then pass it through the function, otherwise it would show garbage values as it is showing in your case.
Kindly initialize it with some values and then pass it.

Sample code for initialization:

```
int x[3][4] = {{0,1,2,3}, {4,5,6,7}, {8,9,10,11}};
```

Each set of inner braces represents one row. In the above example there are total three rows so there are three sets of inner braces.

Comment: sorry but i actually have it initialized in my code and i forgot to initialize it here

Comment: But I just executed the same code and it is showing the correct result, see the code here [link](https://ideone.com/mFOrXR)